# Rails only installed in certain directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I have installed RoR and been using it to follow Michael Hartl's tutorial. However, when I switch to ~/rails_projects/sample_app, and try to run rails, it says it is not installed. Under ~/rails_projects it is installed.

Anyone know why this is, or how I can fix it?

I also get this message when switching to sample_app:

RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/arikgadye/rails_projects/sample_app/Gemfile'.

I have ruby v 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.1

Thank you!

Comment: What's the output of `gem list` in `~/rails_projects/sample_app`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM is switching to the ruby version which is specified in Gemfile. SO it can happen that when you enter the folder it change the version of ruby where there is no rails installed

check what version of ruby is specified in Gemfile and ensure that you installed that version fo ruby with rvm and after this run

```
gem install bundler 
bundle install
```

it should solve the problem